# Pandas apply ValueError: bad input shape() when sending POST request

Tags: python, django, pandas, postman

I am trying to implement an API in a django framework with the following code below:

```
def worker_label_encoder(df,selected_col):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    enc = le.fit(np.unique(df[selected_col]))
    df[selected_col] = df[selected_col].apply(enc.fit_transform)
```

It works fine when I tried it in a script on Atom.
But when I use postman to send POST request with this API, it returns

```
ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

on this line:

```
df[selected_col] = df[selected_col].apply(enc.fit_transform)
```

What is wrong? Why does it work in a script but not in post request?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things wrong in you code.

First apply function should have first argument as the value of column for which you have provided entire dataframe.

Second why are you doing fit and then fit_transform. The standard flow is to either fit_transform or simple fit and transform. You should check this examples [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to understand how LabelEncoder works.

If you want to accomplish what you are trying to do then there is a simpler way like

```
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.selected_col.values)

# Lable encode target variable
df['selected_col'] = le.transform(
    train_df.selected_col.values)
```

If you still have another values then you simply need to do transform. No need to do fit_transform again.